# WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process in a Docker container returns odd errors

Tags: selenium, docker, containers, dockerfile

I'm running a small Python script that scrapes some data from a public website.

When I run the Dockerfile instructions line by line in an interactive terminal using the selenium:latest image the script *runs fine*.

`docker run -it -v /Users/me/Desktop/code/scraper/:/scraper selenium/standalone-firefox bash`

As soon as I run it using my Dockerfile and docker-compose file I get this error:

```
app_1  | selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

I am using the MOZ_HEADLESS=1 env var. It's being passed properly.

I have tried running the script as someone other than root but then I get log errors.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:latest


# https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/725
USER root

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y firefox python-pip

WORKDIR /scraper

COPY . /scraper
RUN pip install -r /scraper/requirements.txt

ENV MOZ_HEADLESS=1
CMD ["python", "/scraper/browserscraper.py"]
```

If I run those instructions in the Dockerfile from an interactive terminal, I have no problems.

It either has to do with the user being root running the script via the Dockerfile or something about it missing a screen for output because I'm not actually SSH'ed in like I am running it from the command line with `-it`.

Any ideas?